# Run tests in celery workers

Tags: python, testing, celery

I'm looking for a Python test-suite that takes tests, converts them into celery tasks which are run on workers, gathers the results and prints them as if the tests were running normally.

Searching only came up with ways of testing celery tasks. I don't want to test celery tasks, I want celery tasks to test other things.

Is there anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any library that uses celery to distribute tests, but there are libraries for both pytest and nose that do something similar.

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-xdist
- https://github.com/dlanger/nose-parallel